# transparent image over opaque background

Tags: html, css, png

**Problem**:

I have a png image as a jquery dialog title. The image corners are transparent (rounded corners)

When I display the dialog over a 50% opaque overlay I see that the corners are not transparent.

**Solution**:

The problem was the positioning of the image as a title. The non-transparent corners were not of the image but of the div containing it. It wasn't transparent even tough I set the background-color to transparent in ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar"

The solution I found is to set the ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar" margin-top property to "-18px" so the png image is positioned outside, hiding the corners of the div

thanks for the help

Comment: it might not actually be as transparent as you think? does it work only on a white page? Maybe you might want to post the image, or link to the image here.

Comment: Please clarify: `I have a png with transparent background.` and then you say `the png's background stops being opaque.` These are two separate images? Also, `but when I display it over a gray overlay` You're putting a transparent image over an overlay. ???

Comment: was my mistake, I thought the the png was the cause of the problem. I edited the question and answered